# Error: While creating clusterless Availbility Group

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2019

I was trying to create Clusterless AlwaysON for SQL Server 2019 and getting the below error.

Error Message:

> Msg 47106, Level 16, State 3, Line 11
> Cannot join availability group '100'. Download configuration timeout. Please check primary configuration, network connectivity and firewall setup, then retry the operation.
> Msg 41158, Level 16, State 3, Line 11
> Failed to join local availability replica to availability group '100'.  The operation encountered SQL Server error 47106 and has been rolled back.  Check the SQL Server error log for more details.  When the cause of the error has been resolved, retry the ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP JOIN command.
> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 15

I ensure following:

- Both SQL server are running in same windows account
- Both accounts has `sysadmin` privileges.
- All firewall settings are off and able ping and connect SQL1 and SQL2

Comment: Is your AG name actually '100'?

Answer (score 2):

> [...] Cannot join availability group '100' [...]

To echo what Dan has said, is this really the name? It's doesn't have to do with the overall issue, but it's a poor name and will most likely confuse people who aren't, well, you.

> Check the SQL Server error log for more details.

Did we check the errorlog for more details? That'd be a helpful start if you want the community to debug this for free dollars.

> Download configuration timeout.

Considering the amount of time this waits for completion, unless these servers are connected to the worst possible networks across vast distances, it's almost purely a configuration issue.

> All firewall settings are off and able ping and connect SQL1 and SQL2

Ping is an ICMP probe, connections to run queries (I assume here, connect means over port TCP 1433 using TDS) are not the same as the database mirroring endpoint which is TCP but on a different port using a different protocol. If you used the built in wizard and left the defaults then that's on port TCP 5022. There's nothing here about whether this is open and the secondary is connected... but we can make an educated guess based on the error that it's probably not at all connected... which goes back to checking the errorlogs as they should show this information.